# How to include javascript actions on onclick event in Yii CHtml::link?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii

> a href="#" id="23" onclick="test(this.id)"

i have to use this type of link in yii itry with below code but still not working.

```
array(
 'value'=>'CHtml::link("View","#", array("id"=>$data["announce_id"],  "class"=>$data["announce_id"], "onclick"=>"test($data[announce_id]); "))',

        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by this way:

```
"onclick"=>"test(".$data["announce_id"]."); "
```

Comment: Not sure that it will work because it seems that the code is used in a CGridView or aCListView and $data doesn't exist when you declare the view. It's interpreted later when datas are fetch from the db

Comment: replaced ' with " now it should